# How to access file resource from python egg when deploying crawler with scrapyd?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I want to load a JSON file from scrapyd, but it never seemed to find the files, whatever referencing method I used.

Normally I had the open method followed by the filename and I put the filename in the eggs root as well as the projects egg folder, but in no case the files were found.

If anyone knows how to do this with a full example, I would be very helpful.

My `setup.py` looks like the following

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import os, sys
directory, filename = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(directory)

setup(
    name='myscraper',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={'scrapy': ['settings = myscraper.local_settings']},
    install_requires=['selenium', 'scrapy', 'pyyaml', 'yamlordereddictloader', 'pyvirtualdisplay'],
    package_data={'mypackage': ['myscraper/configuration/seeds.json', 'myscraper/configuration/*.yml'],
                  },
    data_files=[("mydata", ["myscraper/configuration/seeds.json"])],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False
)
```

The project structure

```
- my_crawler
--- setup.py
--- myscraper
------- configuration
-------------seeds.json
------- myspider.py
------- ...
```

How can I read the json file in `myspider.py`?
How can I read all the yaml files in the configuration folder?

I want to use some code similar with:

```
# how to get the content from seeds.json ?

content = pkgutil.get_data('mypackage', filename)

# how to walk the configuration directory from the egg?

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(config_dir):
        for config_file in files:
            config_file = open(os.path.join(root, config_file))
            config_dict = yaml.load(config_file, Loader=yamlordereddictloader.Loader)
            visit = config_dict.get("visit")
            self.configuration[visit] = config_dict
```

---

- related threads

egg caveats

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd-client

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scrapy-users/B70eq1_N3Fk/vR7aDeizj_sJ

https://support.scrapinghub.com/topics/1717-deploying-projects-with-resource-non-code-files/

https://support.scrapinghub.com/topics/725-including-additional-files-with-a-spider/

Answer (score 0):

```
from png_resources import resource_string
...

    file_string = resource_string(
        __name__.split('.')[0], 
        'myscraper/configuration/seeds.json',
    )
```